# Handlebars: using a javascript variable for index

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
"{{tickets." + index + ".comments.0.account}}"
```

I want to be able to specify the index of the array that I am trying to get data from with a javascript variable. Currently this code gives me an error which says:

```
Expecting 'ID', got 'STRING'
```

I am actually using express-handlebars with Node.js if this makes a difference.

Comment: You don't show enough code.

Answer (score 2):

Create a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getTicketAccount', function(context, i) {
  // Error handling ommitted for brevity
  return context[i].comments[0].account;
});
```

To use:

```
{{getTicketAccount tickets index}}
```